# Size of lightning-helptext icon?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, icon

How can I modify the size of an Icon in lightning-helptext?

My code:

```
<lightning-helptext content={errorLabel} 
icon-variant="error" class="slds-p-right_small" 
icon-name="utility:warning" size="large" if:true={test}>
</lightning-helptext>
```

I tried either size="large" property and aplying custom CSS on class property, and I cannot resize the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, this component does not have any property (or at least [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-helptext/specification)) that allows you to do this.

Instead, use the [blueprints](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tooltips/#site-main-content) to create your own help text and icon

Comment: Thank you! I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use css hooks: 
`:host {`
`--lwc-squareIconMediumContentAlt: 1.25rem;`
`--lwc-squareIconMediumContentAlt: 1.25rem;`
`}`